# Servlet non-lifecycle method call from Browser

Tags: java, servlets

I was wondering if it is possible to call a non-life-cycle method of a servlet directly from the Browser.
For example, just as a sample code if I have something like -

```
public CheckServlet extends HttpServlet {
     public void foo(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
         // do something
     }
}
```

web.xml -

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>CheckServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CheckServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>defpkg.CheckServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CheckServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CheckServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The browser URL -

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/CheckServlet
```

Now if I have to make a call to `foo()` from the browser, is it possible and if yes, how?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible! If it was possible it would be a great security hole as a user of your webapp may call any method!

But your servlet may call want it wants in it's lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet spec (2.5) only supports the following;

- doGet
- doPost
- doPut
- doDelete
- doHead
- doOptions
- doTrace

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can pass in some parameters through either a GET or a POST, The first one would be the name of the action you want to execute and the other ones would be the parameters to pass in. On the Servlet side you would map the different actions to different methods and simply pass in the request parameters.

Comment: hhmm.. I might give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the browser can call in case the web-app is servlet 2.5, The new servlet spec supports custom methods, means the servlet can have doFoo() method, and the browser can call with foo method like any normal GET, POST Http method.